# unknown pseudo-op: `.globl_start'

Tags: assembly, buffer-overflow, gnu-assembler

I have some assembly code written for 32-bit machines but I need to run that on x86-64 bit architecture. Please suggest ways to achieve this.

I'm compiling using certain flags in the following manner:
as --32 -o exec_shell.o exec_shell.s

Error Messages:

exec_shell.s: Assembler messages:
exec_shell.s:2: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.globl_start'

Comment: You should include a minimal code example that can be used to reproduce the problem. One guess is that you're missing a space (that it should be `.globl _start`), but it's hard to say for sure without having seen the code.

Comment: Silly mistake on my part. Space worked perfect. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put space between .globl and _start.
eg.

```
 .text
 .globl _start 
 _start:
```